# Overlap view after delete item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Removing item in RecyclerView cause view overlap like this video
[Link](https://youtu.be/bQs9DOAL614)

fragment_feed.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

In Adapter

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
  ((PostViewHolder) holder).mUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

void deleteItem(int index) {
    postList.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);

}
```

When i change `notifyItemRemoved(index);` to `notifyDataSetChanged();` seem to solved my problem but it's cause remove animation destroyed.
I try to find solution to solve this but It's seem like no one have the same problem with me. Thanks for answer

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    if (holder instanceof PostViewHolder) {
        Post post = (Post) postList.get(position);
        String type = post.getTypePost();

        // Inflate Layout //
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);


        ((PostViewHolder) holder).mUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        ((PostViewHolder) holder).mUsername.setText(post.getOwnerPost());


    } else if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {

    } else{
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing holder.setIsRecyclable(false); line.

Comment: @BharathKumar It's seem to be work but i worried about wrong position in recyclerView. Thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the clickListener in onBindViewHolder and change the code like following

```
PostViewHolder postViewHolder=(PostViewHolder) holder;
postViewHolder.mUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });

void deleteItem(int index) {
    postList.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, yourDataSet.size());
}
holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
```

While deleting always remove item from datalist and then notifyAdapter.
Also use holder.setIsRecyclable(false) when each viewholder data has different data state.

Comment: It's seem to be solved when i remove or change setIsRecyclable(false) to (true). Thanks XD

Comment: SetIsRecyclable is used only when you dont want to recycle the views of recycler..So you were getting error..anyways happy to hear it solved :)

Answer (score 2):

On Your Activity level, where you are binding your adapter with the Recycler View, You need to clear your list before calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Use the following line of code

```
adapter.clearData();
```

and

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And in deleteItem() method:-

```
void deleteItem(int index) {
    postList.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(index, getItemCount() - index);
}
```

For more help you can follow this link:- 
https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
void deleteItem(int index) {
    postList.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);

    //notify items from index to end
    notifyItemRangeChanged(index, getItemCount() - index);
}
```