# Recycler view post Item deletion, has deleted views overlapping other views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313911/overlap-view-after-delete-item-in-recyclerview) solution here, but unfortunately doesnt work in my scenario. 
Ill keep it simple: I have multiple viewHolders with multiple animations for a chat App, 
Since I have no touch listeners to register the adapter position of the typing indicators, I have:
In my `CustomAdapter`

```
private var typingIndicatorAdapterPosition: Int = -1
private var inlineErrorAdapterPosition: Int = -1
```

In my `onBindViewHolder`

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    when (holder.itemViewType) {
     ...
        USER_REQUEST_TEXT -> {
            val userRequestViewHolder = (holder as UserRequestViewHolder)
            configUserRequestViewHolder(userRequestViewHolder, position)
            userRequestViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        }

        TYPE_INDICATOR -> {
            val typingIndicatorViewHolder = (holder as TypingIndicatorViewHolder)
            configTypingIndicatorViewHolder(typingIndicatorViewHolder, position)
            typingIndicatorAdapterPosition = typingIndicatorViewHolder.layoutPosition
            typingIndicatorViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(true)
        }

        INLINE_ERROR -> {
            val inlineErrorViewHolder = (holder as InlineErrorViewHolder)
            configInlineErrorViewHolder(inlineErrorViewHolder, position)
            inlineErrorAdapterPosition = inlineErrorViewHolder.layoutPosition
            inlineErrorViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(true)
        }
    }
}
```

my adapter code for deletion :

```
   fun removeTypingIndicator() {
    if(typingIndicatorAdapterPosition > 0) {
        if(messageContainerList[typingIndicatorAdapterPosition].messageType == TYPE_INDICATOR) {
            messageContainerList.removeAt(typingIndicatorAdapterPosition)
            notifyItemRemoved(typingIndicatorAdapterPosition)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(typingIndicatorAdapterPosition, itemCount - 1)
            typingIndicatorAdapterPosition = -1
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** - I do not prefer `notifyDataSetChanged()` etc. as it cancels the animations.

here are some screen shots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line looks incorrect:

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(typingIndicatorAdapterPosition, itemCount - 1)
```

Assuming you're trying to change all the items from the typing indicator position through the end of the list, it looks like you're trying to use it as `(start, end)`, but the parameters are actually `(start, itemCount)`, with `itemCount` being the number of items changed at that index.  See [the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) for more information.

Comment: I did fix that, you are right about it. But on further research and diagnosis, I feel the problem is about how recycler view enqueues the update operations, the response is coming as a request from a network call, and the deletion op of typing indicator from the list and addition of new incoming messages are resulting in this weird items floating around.